# template specialization of class Stack

Tags: c++, templates

I want to write two different implementations of class Stack.

(1)

```
template<typename element_type, typename container_type = std::vector<element_type> >
   class Stack{//...

    };
```

(2)

```
template<typename element_type, size_t container_size>
   class Stack{
   };
```

If I define both the implementations in a single file I get compiler error. Is it possible to have both of them in the same file?

```
//compiler errors:

Stack.hpp:119:46: error: declaration of template ‘template<class element_type, long unsigned int container_size> int containers::Stack()’
Stack.hpp:25:9: error: conflicts with previous declaration ‘template<class element_type, class container_type> class containers::Stack’
Stack.hpp:25:9: error: previous non-function declaration ‘template<class element_type, class container_type> class containers::Stack’
Stack.hpp:119:46: error: conflicts with function declaration ‘template<class element_type, long unsigned int container_size> int containers::Stack()’
```

Comment: What, pray tell, is the compiler error?

Comment: What error? what compiler?  Plese give more detailed information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to give them two different names if they take different kinds of parameters.

Answer (score 3):

Nope, you can't. You can't have two versions of a templated class with different template parameters. I recommend calling the two kinds of `Stack` differently or putting them in different namespaces.

Answer (score 2):

You have to write something like this:

```
template<typename element_type, typename container_type = std::vector<element_type> >
class Stack {
  // This is *not* the specialization
};

template<typename element_type>
class Stack<element_type, std::vector<element_type> > {
  // Specialization goes here.
};
```

Edit: You can't change the type of the template parameter.